# How can Mockito mock a Kotlin `use` (aka try-with-resource)?

Tags: kotlin, mockito, try-with-resources

If I were trying to add mocks to the following code (where the `MyTypeBuilder` is mocked to return a mocked `MyType` - which implements `Closeable`):

```
myTypeBuilder.build(myTypeConfiguration).use { myType ->
    myType.callMyMethod()
}
```

Then trying to verify interactions with `myType.callMethod()` something like:

```
myType: MyType = mock()
myTypeBuilder: MyTypeBuilder = mock()
whenever(myTypeBuilder.build(any())).thenReturn(myType)
doMethodCall()
verify(myType, times(1)).callMyMethod()
```

I'm getting errors:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
myType.callMethod()
-> at package.me.MyType.callMyMethod(MyType.kt:123)

However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
myType.close()
-> at kotlin.io.CloseableKt.closeFinally(Closeable.kt:57)
```

So it appears that I need to add a `whenever` to execute the `use` block, but I'm not sure what that should look like. Alternatively, the `use` should act like a Mockito spy rather than a mock, but then allow mocking on the other methods.

Comment: It should not be necessary to mock or spy the `use`, because it really does nothing else than calling the given block and then close the closable receiver (see here: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/io/Closeable.kt). The call of `close` in `closeFinally`at line 57 even suggests that the block was called without any exception (otherwise it would have been closed in line 60). Have you tried to debug your test and checked that you really visit the line you are trying to verify?

Comment: Do you inject the mock `myTypeBuilder` as a dependency to `doMethodCall()`?

Comment: @KarstenGabriel That seems to be the issue. Because the class is mocked, the block doesn't get executed. I have done exactly as you suggested (breakpoint in the block), and it appears the entire block is being skipped. But then, as you point out, the `close` method is being called which suggests the runtime is at least aware that there is a resource to be closed. Thanks again for your help. Hopefully the light of a new day will help me understand what's going on :-)

Answer (score 3):

I tried to reconstruct the error by writing the following code which is basically what you wrote in your question plus some `println` statements and some boilerplate to make it runnable:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.mockito.Mockito.*
import org.mockito.kotlin.any
import org.mockito.kotlin.mock
import org.mockito.kotlin.whenever
import java.io.Closeable

open class MyTypeBuilder {
    open fun build(config: Any): MyType {
        println("build")
        return MyType()
    }

}

open class MyType : Closeable {

    fun callMyMethod() {
        println("callMyMethod")
    }

    override fun close() {
        println("close")
    }
}

val myTypeConfiguration: Any = "heyho"

fun call(myTypeBuilder: MyTypeBuilder) {
    myTypeBuilder.build(myTypeConfiguration).use { myType ->
        println("call")
        myType.callMyMethod()
    }
}

class MockAndUseTest {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val myType: MyType = mock()
        val myTypeBuilder: MyTypeBuilder = mock()
        whenever(myTypeBuilder.build(any())).thenReturn(myType)
        call(myTypeBuilder)
        verify(myType, times(1)).callMyMethod()
    }
}
```

When I run the test case `test`, it succeeds and is green.

So, unfortunately whatever may cause your problem, it is not contained in the details given by your question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm afraid that was just a mistake in writing the question. I've edited the question to reflect that. Good catch.

Comment: @AlexTaylor I rewrote my answer, please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for your continued interest. Have an upvote. The fact that yours is working tells me I need to rework this.